# glGet retuns a value that is not up to date

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I want to create the view matrix and get this matrix to the cpu. I am trying this with the code below, but the view matrix 'mViewMatrix' is lagging behind one frame.
I was wondering if it is possible to get the correct view matrix with glGetFloatv or if it is necessary to calculate the matrix on the cpu.

```
class Camera {
    float mViewMatrix[16];
    Vector3 mPos;
    Vector3 mEuler;

    void updateViewMatrix()
    {
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glRotatef(-mEuler.x, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(-mEuler.y, 0, 1, 0);
        glRotatef(-mEuler.z, 0, 0, 1);
        glTranslatef(-mPos.x, -mPos.y, -mPos.z);

        glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mViewMatrix);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is elsewhere. It's important that you post your *real code* (`mEuler` twice? no semicolons? it's not your real code) and explain how you got to the conclusion that `mViewMatrix` is lagging. Also you should know that all those calls already run exclusively on the CPU, so you can just as well calculate those yourself. Additionally, the fixed-function pipeline is deprecated for more than half a decade, so you are better start using modern OpenGL.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I copied a part out of the real code, because the real code is quite large. I noticed that the view matrix wasn't up to date, because forward, up, and right stayed the same for one frame after teleportation. When I replace the glGetFloatv above with a function that calculates the view matrix, everything works like expected, so glGetFloatv is part of the problem or the problem.

Comment: I am not verry experienced with openGL and, the fixed pipeline seemed like a better choice for a quick prototype. Is this correct?

Comment: @KayGoossen For a quick prototype a more high-level solution would typically be a better choice.

Comment: I'm prototyping everything with OpenGL 4.5 Core. So much easier.

Comment: If this is really the way you describe, it could be simply a bug in the OpenGL implementation. Try it on a different machine/platform, ideally with a GPU from a different vendor, to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the call with Push & Pop matrix calls, glGet will return the value on the top of the matrix stack:

```
glPushMatrix();
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, mViewMatrix);
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: How would this help? `glPushMatrix()` just copies the top element of the matrix stack. The value on top of the matrix stack will be exactly the same, except that it's on the stack twice.